# Session and Cookie problem in vMix Data Source

Tags: php, json, broadcasting

I have created JSON output in PHP that use session or cookie. If I look my JSON based PHP file over web browser, then data is showed, but if I put the same link in vMix Data Source JSON source, then it is not showing anything. Source is blank (empty).

How can I use session or cookie based JSON PHP page in vMix Data Source?

PHP JSON

```
<?php
    include("database.php");
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['firstname'])){
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    $first_name = $_SESSION['firstname'];
    $sql_name = "select * from admin where f_name='".$first_name."'";
    $fetch = mysqli_query($db,$sql_name); $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch); 
    
    $name = $rows['f_name'];

    $data[] = array("first_name"=>"$name");
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
[{"first_name":"Mario"}]
```

vMix Data Source
[vMix Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN2Ze.jpg)

Comment: you can't sessions require cookies which is a header that has to be saved and sent by the HTTP client, if vMix does not support that you can't do it.

Comment: what is solution?

Comment: You have to create an access key you can send via $_GET params but then you need to make sure you're using an HTTP2 SSL Secured server or they are sent unencrypted and then open to MITM attacks, it's not a simple thing, and even then still insecure.

Comment: Do you have some example? it may also not be safe. That name is not import other one.

Comment: sorry, if you don't know how to use `$_GET` you need to do some basic stuff in PHP first your trying to jump into the deep end here and this site is not here to do work for free for people we're here to help people learn when they get something wrong.